# UpdateProgress Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an asp.net page which does most of the work in the c# code-behind. I am using update panels and would like to set an UpdateProgress control to display a PleaseWait.gif image while processing is happening... The processing is initiated by pressing the 'select' link button on a GridView. I am having trouble getting the UpdateProgress to display.. My question is: how should I wire-up the UpdateProgress to display on this 'select' button press?

(Any Idea why this isnt working...)
CODE:

```
asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="SelectCarUP" DisplayAfter="10">
                    <ProgressTemplate>
                        <asp:Image src="~/App_Themes/defaultCSU/PleaseWait.gif" ID="PleaseWait" runat="server" />
                    </ProgressTemplate>
                </asp:UpdateProgress>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="SelectCarUP" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="VehiclesGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="VehiclesEDS" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                onselectedindexchanged="VehiclesGridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="GVSelectButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

           ..........
```

Comment: Try UpdateMode="Always" and see if there is any difference...

Comment: Changing UpdateMode to 'always' seems to work, however now it displays a 'broken' image icon. (I did include and check that the source is valid)

Comment: Ok, it seems that it doesn't like my use of '~' for the root folder for some reason. The image url evaluates to: http://localhost:25358/Ops/~/img/PleaseWait.gif instead of localhost/img/PleaseWait.gif ...One step closer, but any thoughts on this one ?

Comment: yes don't use src, use ImageUrl, which is the server side property.  src translates directly and hence the problem.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `UpdateMode="Always"` and use `ImageUrl` property on the image, as in:

```
<asp:Image id="i" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/defaultCSU/PleaseWait.gif" />
```

Also, because of application themes, you may not have to path from App_Themes, but can from defaultCSU folder...

Answer (score 1):

The process UpdateProgress have notthing to show as it is now, and this is run with javascript the moment you press and wait for data. So probably the UpdateProgress is open, but have nothing to show.

**Please an image and a text and check again if its working.**

Comment: I did accidentally forget the src= when copying over, I now have it displaying when I want it to with updatemode set to 'always', but it showing a 'broken' image icon. I'm sure the source is valid, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only work necessary is to bind the UpdateProgress control to the UpdatePanel with the AssociatedUpdatePanelID, which you have done. Right now, your image tag doesn't have an associated file. Are you sure it isn't trying to show but the file isn't found?

Try changing your image to some text to be sure the image isn't the problem